# Setting boolean and array values using wp theme mod set

Tags: wp-cli

I need to set a couple of Theme Mods to boolean and array values using WP CLI but can't find any way to do achieve it.

I have already tried the following for booleans, but they appear to be treated as string:

```
wp theme mod set my_theme_mod true
wp theme mod set my_theme_mod 1
```

For arrays, I don't even know where to start, so have not tried anything yet.

Any pointers please?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible. [Looking at the implementation](https://github.com/wp-cli/extension-command/blob/master/src/Theme_Mod_Command.php#L238-L248) it just passes the `$value` argument. So if it doesn't behave correctly right now, I'm not sure how you can better force it. You [can create an issue in their GitHub](https://github.com/wp-cli/extension-command/issues).

Comment: Thanks, found a way to achieve it. A bit of a round about way to do it, but gets the required result and actually a lot more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny how you find the answer just after posting a question. Posting here, in case someone comes looking for it.

As per @Kero's comment above, that's correct. The command-line option will only recognise strings.

There is however an eval-file command that can be used to achieve this (and now that I have discovered it, a lot more).

Here are the steps for achieving the goal I posted in my question, however as the eval-file WP CLI command can be used to execute a PHP file, we can code anything that we deem fit.

Step 1: Create a PHP file with the required code. In my example here, I added the following:

```
<?php
set_theme_mod('my_boolean_mod', false);
set_theme_mod('my_array_mod', array(1, 2, 3));
```

The above code will use the WordPress [set_theme_mod](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_theme_mod/) function to create/update mods named my_boolean_mod and my_array_mod.

Step 2: Execute the above file using the WP CLI eval-file command

```
 wp eval-file my_file.php
```

That's it. Hope this is useful!